# Error when attaching depth/stencil buffer to the framebuffer

Tags: opengl, depth-buffer, stencil-buffer

I create a depth/stencil buffer by issuing this series of command to OpenGL:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)
glGenTextures(1, &TextureId)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TextureId)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE_MODE, GL_INTENSITY)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL_COMPARE_R_TO_TEXTURE)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC, GL_LEQUAL)
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, 640, 480,  0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)
```

Then I try and attach it to the framebuffer with

```
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, TextureId, 0)
```

But a call to `glCheckFramebufferStatusEXT` returns `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT`. If I don’t attach the depth-stencil buffer, this very test goes fine (but obviously the display is screwed).

Do you guys have any clue?

**EDIT**:
Changed: I have simplified the texture creation to a basic texture’s format.

Comment: Any GL errors being triggered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, the problem disappeared when I removed all the trailing EXT…

Comment: I think you learned that you can't mix extensions and core in the same functionality.

Answer (score 2):

The texture you're attaching to `GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT` has neither depth nor stencil information in it. If you want to attach a texture to `GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT`, you make sure it's image format has [depth and stencil data](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format#Depth_stencil_formats).

Answer (score 1):

Now OpenGL versions does not need EXT extension~~~

Comment: I thought they would still be supported for backward compatibility, but apparently mixing both EXT and non-EXT versions is not okay :)